# socket.io client doesn't connect, but the server recognize it

Tags: node.js, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I've developed an application using socket.io and it works correctly on the development environment. When I implemented to the testing server the client doesn't fire the onConnect function and pending. Then I find that the server does recognize the connection and fire the onConnect (as i see the logs).

I use IIS reverse-proxy to comply with our infrastructure architecture and route the request to the node.js server (that runs the socket.io) public https to private http.

I suspect this may be the problem. I also found that safari and firefox can connect to the socket but not with chrome and I notice there is this header when I inspect the request

> Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Is your IIS reverse proxy configured to work with webSocket connections and allow them to stay connected for a long duration?

Comment: Yes, I think. Because its running well on safari and firefox.

Comment: That header implies you may be trying to make an insecure webSocket connection from an https page.  Is that the case?

Comment: Yup, that what i guess.

Comment: Well different browsers may have different restrictions about making an http connection from an https page.

Comment: So you think i should make the internal request a https as well?

Comment: Yes.  Chrome doesn't like you making insecure connections from within an https page.